# POO como hago para hacer este metodo de tipo objeto

Tags: java

1.estos son mis atributos, y mi constructor

```
private Punto origen;
    private double ancho;
    private double alto;
    public Rectangulo (Punto p_origen, double p_ancho, double p_alto){
        this.setorigen(p_origen);
        this.setancho(p_ancho);
        this.setalto(p_alto);
        }
   
    
    

public double  distanciaA(Rectangulo otroRectangulo){
    return this.distanciaA(this.getorigen()) - this.getorigen();
}*// mi problema esta en este metodo *//
```

2. quiero calcular la distancia de un objeto rectangulo a otro objeto rectangulo a partir del origen de cada uno pero me dice error porque origen es de tipo punto y no puede ser convertido a rectangulo o algo asi, alguien que me puede explicar ? gracias!

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente lo que estas preguntando.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema exactamente es ese que te dice, origen es de tipo Punto (Un objeto de la clase Punto) y el método espera hacer cálculos y retornar un valor double, cosa que es imposible ya que no es un numero.

1- El método espera retornar un valor de tipo double 
2- Solo se pueden hacer cálculos con números.

En otras palabras no podes hacer esto -> `this.getorigen()) - this.getorigen()`

Lo que si podrías hacer es esto `getorigen().getX()` y hacer operaciones.

Entonces digamos que tu clase Punto tiene algunas variables como el X e Y en un plano cartesiano...

Y tienes que calcular las distancias entre dos Puntos, la formula interpretada a código seria algo así

La formula interpretada a código seria algo así:

```
public double distance(Punto punto) {
    double locX = punto.getX() - getX();
    double locY = punto.getY() - getY();
        
    return Math.sqrt(locX * locX + locY * locY);
}
```

Como ves en el parámetro pide un objeto Punto, pero luego uso las variables getX y getY para hacer cálculos, tu lo que hiciste fue restar objetos `origen` de tipo Punto

Imagina ahora que estas creando un juego tienes a los jugadores con la clase `Player` y cada uno tiene una clase `Location` que es la ubicacion del jugador en el mapa.

La clase Location se vería algo así:

```
public class Location {

    private double x, y;

    public Location(double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public double getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public double getY() {
        return y;
    }
    
    public double distance(Location location) {
        double locX = location.getX() - getX();
        double locY = location.getY() - getY();
        
        return Math.sqrt(locX * locX + locY * locY);
    }

}
```

Para ver la distancia entre un jugador y otro seria algo así: `player1.getLocation().distance(player2.getLocation())`

Entonces tu clase `Rectangulo` seria como la clase `Player` y adentro tiene un objeto de clase `Punto`, que seria como la clase `Location`

Siguiendo todo esto que acabe de decir y teniendo la clase Punto como si fuera la clase Location, al final la clase Rectangulo quedaría así, dejando a la clase Punto que haga cosas propias a su clase por ejemplo calcular las distancias entre 2 puntos.

```
public class Rectangulo {
        
    private Punto punto;
    private int ancho, alto;
        
    public Rectangulo(Punto punto, int ancho, int alto) {
        this.punto = punto;
        this.ancho = ancho;
        this.alto = alto;
    }
        
    public int getAncho() {
        return ancho;
    }
        
    public int getAlto() {
        return alto;
    }
        
    public Punto getPunto() {
        return punto;
    }
        
}
```

Espero te sirva, la respuesta es un poco larga pero solo por los ejemplos de código, la explicación en si es bastante simple.

Comment: si me sirvió muchísimas gracias por los ejemplos y explicación!